# Pool of std:wstring. Is this approach too naive?

Tags: c++

I was playing with some code and I wrote this little class to pool std::wstring. As I profile it I'd like to know your oppinion about approaching a pool of strings this simple.

I have a std::vector of std::wstring and two maps, one for holding the indexes of the unused elements in the vector and another for the ones that are being used.

If a string is requested with new_string() and there isn't any free indexes left, I resize the vector and insert the newly added indexes to the free indexes map.

Here is the code:

```
typedef std::wstring string_t;

class string_pool
{
    public:
        string_pool()
        {
            grow_factor = 2;
            strings.resize(10);
            for (size_t i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                free_indexes.insert(std::make_pair(&strings[i],i));
            }
        }

        virtual ~string_pool()
        {

        }

        string_t* new_string()
        {
            if (!free_indexes.size())
            {
                size_t old_size = strings.size();
                size_t new_size = old_size+grow_factor;
                for (size_t i=old_size;i<new_size; i++)
                {
                    free_indexes.insert(std::make_pair(&strings[i],i));
                }
                strings.resize(new_size);
            }
            iter = free_indexes.begin();
            used_indexes.insert(*iter);     // Mark the index as used
            string_t* str = (*iter).first;    // Get a pointer to the string
            free_indexes.erase(iter);       // Erase the free index
            return str;
        }

        void delete_string(string_t* str)
        {
            str->clear();
            iter = used_indexes.find(str);
            free_indexes.insert(*iter);     // Mark the index as free
            used_indexes.erase(iter);       // Erase the used index
        }

    protected:
        std::map<string_t*, size_t>             used_indexes;
        std::map<string_t*, size_t>             free_indexes;
        std::vector<string_t>                   strings;
        size_t                                  grow_factor;
        std::map<string_t*, size_t>::iterator   iter;
};
```

Comment: You should turn this into a _statefull allocator_ and do some real world benchmarking...

Comment: Your maps are going to be filled with dangling pointers because they get invalidated when you resize the vector.

Comment: True. Maybe an std::deque and push_back would do the trick? I wonder if this'd be faster than newing/deleting the strings directly...

Comment: I think you're approaching the optimization from the wrong end. You should tell us more about the problem you're trying to solve so we can help you tackle it from a different angle.

Comment: I'm in the first stages of making a scripting language to interact with an application of mine if only for learning purposes. I am currently determining how am I going to instance variables when I push them onto the stack. I already implemented an object pool for non string types and for the case of string containers I pretend to use, for now, this pool I showed above. That's pretty much what I am doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `new`/`delete` you care about is not allocation of the `string` descriptors, but the `string` data.  Pooling `string` objects doesn't help much, the content will still be dynamically allocated.

Comment: That's true. Sadly for std::wstring there seem to be no allocators for boost::pool, and still I've read that pooling chunks of variable size can be worst than actually allocating them with new.

So for the sake of at least avoiding allocating the string container I came up with this.

Comment: @damian: `std::wstring` doesn't need special allocators; any STL-compatible allocator will do.